# AI and cognitive services for name suggestions

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, ibm-watson, azure-cognitive-services

I have a scenario where I am trying to perform some fuzzy matching on some names and derive the probability of suggested matches to the input.  E.g. We have a name supplied "Elizabeth Jones".  Is there any API that would provide alternative names should I supply "Liz Jones" to the API.  What I would like is for the below to be supplied back

```
Elizabeth Jones
Liz Jones
E. Jones
E Jones
```

I know there are a number of cognitive services available and AI can derive the context i.e. "invoice" will supply, "bill, statement, invoice" back but I've seen nothing with names.

Has anyone faced a similar need?

Comment: May be Facebook api, for their people search suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can try [babynames](https://www.programmableweb.com/api/baby-names)

This may help you at least get you to a dictionary of names hopefully this.